# How to copy multiple elements' HTML code in Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I want to copy all the HTML code of elements with class "abc" and I've tried typing `$('.abc')` in the console of Chrome DevTools. It returns an array but I can't expand them all together and copy them to another place...

Is there any trick on doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var arr = $(".abc").map(function () {
    return this.innerHTML; // or $(this).html();
}).get().join(' NextValue ');
```

[.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

put directly on console

```
$(".abc").map(function () {
    return this.innerHTML;
}).get().join(' NextValue ');
```

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery $(selector) will create a jQuery element of live node but not give the html to get the html there is a function in jQuery which is `.html()`

Use this for the required result :

```
$(".abc").html();
```

**Update**

If there are multiple node with class "abc" then you have to loop in using jQuery function `$.each`.
Use this for getting html of all nodes :

```
$(".abc").each(function(){
  $(this).html(); // you can do anything with this hml
});
```

Comment: how can I serialize the results directly to a file?